# "Ambiguous use of prefix" compiler error with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I just migrated my project from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0 with Xcode 8 beta.

I have something similar to the following code (you can paste this into a playground):

```
import Foundation

let datesWithCount: [(Date, Int)] = [(Date(), 1), (Date(), 2), (Date(), 3)]

let dates: [Date] = datesWithCount.sorted {
    $0.0 < $1.0
}.prefix(1).map {
    return $0.0
}
```

In Swift 2.2 this compiled fine. However, with Swift 3.0 I get the error

> Ambiguous use of 'prefix'

The only way to get this to compile in Swift 3.0 is to split out the map into a separate line:

```
let sortedDatesWithCount = datesWithCount.sorted {
    $0.0 < $1.0
}.prefix(1)

let mappedDates = sortedDatesWithCount.map {
    return $0.0
}
```

BTW, in the actual code I'm returning `NSNotification` objects from the `map` not `Date`s but the error is the same. I just used `Date` here for making the example simple.

Is there any way to get this to compile as a one liner?

UPDATE: Created a [JIRA](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1856) for the Swift project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works if you make the ArraySlice into an Array before passing it to `map`:

```
let dates: [Date] = Array(datesWithCount.sorted {
    $0.0 < $1.0
}.prefix(1)).map { return $0.0 }
```

This *looks like* a type inference bug in the compiler.

Comment: Date conforms to protocol Comparable in Swift 3. `sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }` should be enough

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. That's very good news! // I'm just using OP's code, and they say Date is just an example anyway. :)

Comment: Looks like a type inference bug to me too. I'm going to report it as such.
@LeoDabus thanks for the tip about sorting Dates. The real code is actually sorting on Dates too. The example bit is returning Dates from the map.

Comment: Question and Eric's answer updated to shorter sort syntax :)

Comment: @mluisbrown I'm running into this same issue in multiple places in my code where the value I'm `prefix`ing is `[SomeClass]` – did you find anything else out about this issue (I can't use the above workaround)?

Comment: @Blixt If you can't use this solution it means your issue has some specifics that we have to know about before being able to help - I suggest you post a new question. :)

Comment: @EricAya The specifics is that my function already returns `[Type]` so I can't perform the `.prefix(…)` earlier. Since this appears to be a bug (recreating a simple example in Playground doesn't exhibit the issue), I'm mostly interested in @mluisbrown's information.

Comment: One of the cases where I encounter this: https://twitter.com/blixt/status/774268313673273344

Comment: For future reference: I found the issue that @mluisbrown created (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1856) and the cause of this bug is what comes *after* the `.prefix(...)`, so the solution is actually to just make sure the `prefix` call is the last one (break into multiple variables if necessary).

Comment: SR-1856 has been fixed, and the original code compiles with Swift 4.1 (beta)