# Is this a Swift 4 compiler error?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, higher-order-functions

I wrote a little playground to demonstrate how to sort an array coordinates to find the 5 closest. I use higher-order functions, mapping the coordinates to a struct that also contained a distance, sorted it, and then picked the top 5 items. However, I can't do the final part of picking the top 5 as part of the same compound statement.

Below is the code:

```
    import Foundation
    import CoreLocation

    let currentLatitide = 19.1553902
    let currentLongitude = 72.8528602
    struct CoordStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
        let coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        let distance: Double

        var description: String {
            return "lat: " + String(format: "%.4f",coord.latitude) +
                ", long: " + String(format: "%.4f",coord.longitude) + ", distance: " + distance.description
        }
    }

    let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitide, longitude: currentLongitude)

     let points =   [[19.5,71.0],[18.5,72.0],[19.15,72.85],[19.1,75.0],[19.2,70.0],[19.3,70.0],[19.4,70.0],[19.6,70.0],[19.7,70.2],[19.9,70.3],[25,62.0],[24.5,73.4],[23.5,65.0],[21.5,68.0],[20.5,69.0]]

    let structs: [CoordStruct] = points.map //This is where the error shows up.
        {
        let thisCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0[0], longitude: $0[1])
        let thisLocation = CLLocation(latitude:$0[0], longitude: $0[1])
        let distance = location.distance(from: thisLocation)
        return CoordStruct(coord: thisCoord, distance: distance)
        }
        .sorted { $0.distance < $1.distance }
        //----------------------------------
        .prefix(5)  //This won't compile
        //----------------------------------
    let first5Structs = structs.prefix(5)


    first5Structs.forEach { print($0) }

let test = points.map { $0[1] }
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }
    .prefix(5)

print(test)
```

See the line marked `//This won't compile`. With that line un-commented, the compiler says "ambiguous reference to member 'map'" in reference to the map statement. If I comment out the offending line and do a prefix on a separate line, the compiler is happy. The error message makes no sense, which seems typical of the Swift compiler, but the code seems like it SHOULD compile. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931303/2227743 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, the issue is caused by a return type mismatch.

- The annotated type is `Array<CoordStruct>`
- `prefix` returns `ArraySlice<CoordStruct>`

It compiles if you change the line to

```
let structs : ArraySlice<CoordStruct> = points.map { ...
```

Comment: Another option is to omit the type annotation, and to make the closure type explicit: `let structs = points.map{ point -> CoordStruct in ...} ...`

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now that you explain it. I wish Swift errors weren't so obtuse!